# How do I reference text boxes using a variable

Tags: javascript, html

So I am making a small quiz on JavaScript for the first time. I wanted the user to be able to select between 3 options(a, b and c) by entering the letter in a text box and clicking a button to check the answer. A text will then appear underneath the text box to show whether the user entered the right option or not.

I have managed to make this work but since there are multiple questions, I wanted to use a `for` loop to loop through each text box (I named each text box "0", "1" ...) but I cannot reference them using `i`. How can I do it?

Here is my JavaScript:

```
var answer = ["a", "b", "c"];
var results = "results"

function check() {
    for (i = 1; i = 4; i++) {
        var input = document.getElementById(i).value;

        if (input == answer[parseInt(i-1)]) {
            document.getElementById(results.concat(i)).innerHTML = "Correct";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(results.concat(i)).innerHTML = "Wrong";
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the HTML (I repeated the same code for each question with a different ID):

```
<input type="text" id="0" value="a, b or c"><br>
<input type=button value="Check" onClick="check()"><br>
Result: <span id="results0"></span><br><br>
```

Comment: please include the HTML. We will need to see how you are identifying the elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:
There are a few things wrong with your original code

Wrong:

```
for (i = 1; i = 4; i++)
```

usually we start our iterations on 0 index, also the middle portion of the for loop should return truthy which means it should evaluate to true or false "i = 4" will never be either because = is an assignment operator, you should use evaluation operators >, <, >=, ==, etc.

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var input = document.getElementById(i).value;

        if (input == answer[i]) {
            document.getElementById("results" + i).innerHTML = "Correct";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("results" + i).innerHTML = "Wrong";
        }
    }
```

Additionally you were using "result" like a variable in this:

```
results.concat(i)
```

So results would need to be a variable that contains the string "results" which I doubt is the case. so what we are telling the getElementById method by doing it this way

```
document.getElementById("results" + i)
```

is to find an element with an ID of "results" plus the index of the loop eg. id="result0", or id="result1" etc.

Comment: Thanks this worked. However, I am still getting an error message. Any ideas why? Here is the error "JavaScript error: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById(i).value') on line 8"

Comment: document.getElementById(i).value is looking for an element with the ID of whatever "i" is. So assuming i is 0 then the element would have to be id="0" in order to find it. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think I may know whats going on here you may be looking for an element that doesn't exist if you have 3 elements 0,1,2 then you are looking for 3 that doesn't exist you will get the error. see my edit to the answer i < 3 in the loop.

Comment: Yep that's perfect! Thanks so much

Comment: If you would accept the correct answer that would be helpful to the community. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have all of these within a `<div>` or div tag you can reference them using :nth-child notation. This works by referencing the nth child from the beginning.

```
$("div:nth-child(i)");
```

Comment: The poster made no reference to using jQuery.

Comment: jQuery was tagged right? If not I apologize and I shall take down my post.

Comment: @Alan - The original post did, but he removed it.

Answer (score 0):

**Looping through id's feels very dirty to me. From a maintenance and readability standpoint, I recommend you loop through a collection of Nodes instead.**

I believe that you are looking for:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("someClass")[0];
```

Where [0] Would be the index of the element whos class is shared.

Here is a code sample I wrote for you to reference using textboxes and outputting the values into a div within a for loop.

https://jsfiddle.net/4ocnyy38/1/

Answer (score 0):

With the html you provided your for loop is incorrect.

Since you started your input at 0 you want to start looping at 0.

```
for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) { //with three values 0,1,2
  ...
}
```

Your `<span>` tag also need to be closed with a `</span>`

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically create inputbox and result span and alot dynamic ids to them and then check the correct answer on click of button

Javascript:

```
var answer = ["a", "b", "c"];
var results = "results";
setTimeout(function(){
var injectData='';
for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
injectData+="<input type='text' id='id_"+i+"' placeholder='a, b or c'/> Result: <span id='results_"+i+"'></span><br/>";
}
document.getElementById('inject').innerHTML=injectData;
},500);
function check() {
    for (i = 0; i <3; i++) {
        var input = document.getElementById('id_'+i).value;

        if (input == answer[i]) {
            document.getElementById("results_"+i).innerHTML = "Correct";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("results_"+i).innerHTML = "Wrong";
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="inject">

</div>
<input type=button value="Check" onClick="check();"><br>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/9ea46of5/